# Below and including 4.4.4 vector color is not working

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

here is my svg badge_label_24dp.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="18.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/green_color" //#16b621
    android:pathData="M0,0 l24,0 l-2,9 l2,9 l-24,0z"/>
```

Here is My TextView

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_special_badges"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_label_24dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/tiny_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:text="Recommended"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
```

below and including 4.4.4 icon is of black color 
 [image]

While on other phone it work properly an show green color.

Comment: Even I am also facing the same problem, I used hard coded color

Comment: yes hard coded color is working fine

Comment: what does `getResources().getColor(R.color.green_color)` return?